# Cordova doesn't load photos in iOS emulator

Tags: ios, cordova, emulation, photos

I have tried to load the photos from an example Cordova application. I have copied the full example code from Cordova's website and inserted permission into the `config.xml` file:

```
<plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>  
...
```

I have uploaded a video about my problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5sPYVRqIEY

Update:
Here is content of cordova_plugins.js file:

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.console/www/console-via-logger.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.console.console",
        "clobbers": [
            "console"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.console/www/logger.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.console.logger",
        "clobbers": [
            "cordova.logger"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/www/device.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.device.device",
        "clobbers": [
            "device"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/www/CameraConstants.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.camera.Camera",
        "clobbers": [
            "Camera"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/www/CameraPopoverOptions.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraPopoverOptions",
        "clobbers": [
            "CameraPopoverOptions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/www/Camera.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.camera.camera",
        "clobbers": [
            "navigator.camera"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/www/ios/CameraPopoverHandle.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraPopoverHandle",
        "clobbers": [
            "CameraPopoverHandle"
        ]
    }
];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{
    "org.apache.cordova.console": "0.2.9",
    "org.apache.cordova.device": "0.2.10",
    "org.apache.cordova.camera": "0.3.0"
}
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

Comment: are you really using 2.5 (current version of Cordova is 3.5)?  If not, perhaps the sample code doesn't work with current versions.

Comment: i'm using version 3.5.0 of Cordova. I have tried this code from the 3.5.0:

function getPhoto(source) {
      
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

But the result is same......

the 'source' variable's value is pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY

Comment: did you configured your plugin in cordova_plugin.js

Comment: Hmmm.... i just installed the 'Camera' plugin with Cordova. Like this: 'cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera'

Comment: .. Or it isn't enough?

Comment: i found the log of the Safari's javascript-debugger:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.camera.getPicture')

Comment: i found the log of the iOS Simulator's log:
Aug  6 23:57:50 MysteryKes-MacBook-Pro.local Masodik[1811] : Resetting plugins due to page load.
Aug  6 23:57:50 MysteryKes-MacBook-Pro.local Masodik[1811] : Finished load of: file:///Users/mysteryke/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/E605114B-96D9-443E-801F-8FF1FB4C27D4/Masodik.app/www/index.html
Aug  7 00:00:02 MysteryKes-MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[1435] : 2014-08-07 00:00:02.809|1435|0xe1bf580: Region monitoring not available or enabled. Trigger ignored!

Comment: You might benefit from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702843/api-phonegap-3-3-0-camera-for-ios-not-working

Had a very similar issue, and using 'phonegap local plugin add' seemed to do the trick